# I can't grab a token variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this function to make a token verification using a MongoDB that save it in a past step in my app's logic (and it save it flawlessly)

```
async confirmationPost (req, res) {
    // find the token
    const token = req.body.token;
    await Token.findOne({ token }, function (token) {
        if (!token) return res.status(),
        console.log(token),
        console.log('We cannot find this token.'),

        // After find the token, find the user
        User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, token: req.body.token }, function (err, user) {

            if (!user) return res.status(400).send(body),
                console.log('Coudn't find this user.');

            if (user.isVerified) return res.status(400).send({ 
                type: 'already-verified', msg: 'User already verified.' 
                },
                console.log('Already Verified.')
            );

            // Verify and save
            user.isVerified = true;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                res.status(200).send('Verified, just login.');
                },
                console.log('Verified, just login.')
            );
        });
    });
}
```

But for some reason that I don't understand, in the backend `console.log(token)` returns `null` shows `console.log('We cannot find this token.')` and the application crashes at this point, and show me this message:
*TypeError: Cannot read property '_userId' of null*

The frontend is in React and this is the code from it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function Check({ history }) {

    const [token, setToken] = useState('');

    async function confirmationPost (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const response =  await api.post('/confirm', {
            token: token,
        })

        // history.push('/profile');
    }

    return (
        <>  
            <p className="big">Coloque o token <strong>que você recebeu via email</strong> no campo abaixo abaixo.</p>

            <form onSubmit={confirmationPost}>

                <input 
                type="txt" 
                id="token" 
                placeholder="Coloque o token de verficação aqui, pfvr..."
                value={token}
                onChange={event => setToken(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <p className="little">&nbsp;</p>

            <button className="btn" type="Submit">Verificar token</button>

            </form>

            <p className="little"></p>
            <p className="little">Precisa receber outro token de verificação? Clique bem <strong>aqui</strong>.</p>

        </>
    )
}
```

And thás my Token model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 86400 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Token', TokenSchema);
```

I'm using
NodeJS 10.16.3, Mongoose 5.7.6 and Cors 2.8.5 in the backend and Axios 0.19.0 in the frontend.

Thanks a lot!

Please, feel free to ask me more details about it ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to organize the logic!!! First I check if I had all the info in req, and turn it into a variable:

```
const token_ = req.body.token;
```

After that, I load it in my function and renamed it for clarity and restruturate `token` in `Token.findOne()`:

```
await Token.findOne({ token:token_ }, function (err, tokenData)
```

Off course I changed `(!token)` to `(!tokenData)`. And to finish, just before `User.findOne` I extract the userID from `tokenData` and pass it the function:

```
tokenUser = tokenData._userId;
User.findOne({ _id: tokenUser }, function (err, user) { ... });
```

And it works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

> When executing a query with a callback function, you specify your query as a JSON document. The JSON document's syntax is the same as the MongoDB shell.

So I believe doing `{token}` in `findOne` might not work.

Try replacing it like this

```
 await Token.findOne({ token:token }, function (token) {
  //Callback Logic
})
```

Also the `console.log('We cannot find this token.')` will always gets printed because its after return statement, to fix that you can do this

```
 await Token.findOne({ token:token }, function (token) {
      if(!token){
        console.log('We cannot find this token.')
        return res.status(404)

     } else{
          //Rest of the logic
      }

})
```

Comment: No changes, @Shivam ... Token value still returns "null" as well as the "TyperError" din't change :-(

Comment: At least, the application insn't crashing anymore :-)

Comment: Can you share the model of `Token`

Comment: @Shivan, for the sake of readability, I edited my question :-)

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(req.body.token)` to check if you are receiving a token or not?

Comment: Shivan, yes, `console.log(req.body.token)` returns the right token number!

Comment: And sorry for mispelled your name :-)